# How to config and install Phundament 3 with MySQL?

Tags: yii, content-management-system, yii-extensions, phundament

Downloaded and place [**phundament3**](http://phundament.com/) in local machine, ya its working but not when trying to config /install it with Mysql database followed like [installation doc](https://github.com/schmunk42/phundament/wiki/Installation) ,
where I can find its **Mysql** dump?
 if **installation** do all for me then how to do in local? can any one explain steps,
using Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: seems like migration not working for me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accidentally mixed up your installation, eg. you've installed Phundament with a SQLite database (which is the default), but you want to install it with MySQL, take the following steps:

- update Yii's `db` component in `config/main.php` to run with your MySQL database; *Note: by default Phundament's `console.php` uses the same components as the web-app.*
- go to your web app folder and run `./yiic migrate`
- you should see a list of migrations to be applied, answer `yes` to start the migration

All migrations should now run again, just with your MySQL database.